# Fabric Answers for overall app usage?

Tags: ios, swift, google-fabric

I want to install Fabric Answers to track app users usage.

In my project, I need to specify which actions to track, and add fabric code inside specific functions.

I was wondering if I there is a way to just get generic usage info (such as which are the most viewed screens, without inject Fabric code in the app). So that the stats don't need to be detailed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fabric Answers will give you some very handy information by default, such as session duration, number of installs, active users etc.

To get specific information for custom events or screen views you will need to add code in your app to tell Fabric when these things happen. They are quite easy to configure and send.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. If you don't add any tag, you will have informations on the "audience", ( like iDevice version, OS version, and so on ), but Fabric won't return any other information